# nmcli to connect to specific bssid in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, networkmanager

I have two diff wifi APs with same SSID.
I tried to use **nmcli** to connect to a specific *BSSID* but failed.

Can anybody help?

```
# nmcli -f "in-use,ssid,mode,chan,rate,signal,bars,security,bssid" dev wifi list |grep "AC5300 "
*  ASUS_AC5300                Infra  9     54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2       34:97:F6:6E:31:20 
   ASUS_AC5300                Infra  10    54 Mbit/s  82      ▂▄▆█  WPA2       88:D7:F6:88:AC:30

# nmcli dev wifi connect ASUS_AC5300 bssid 88:D7:F6:88:AC:30
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Active connection removed before it was initialized
```

This command seems to be worked on ubuntu 14.04. I dunno why.

Comment: Seems more suitable for the [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) sections of StackExchange

Comment: I confirmed that the nmcli (v0. 9.8) in ubuntu 14.04 works without any problem. But the nmcli (v1.2.6) in ubuntu 16.04 does not.